# I wanted to scrape article titles from a website but result shows none

Tags: python, web-scraping

I wanted to scrape titles of news articles from new york times website and add it to a list but the result shows an empty list.

when I put just 'a' in the `soup.findAll` line, it works fine(it prints all the links) but when I changed it to class, it doesn't work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_titles():

    tlist = []
    url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
    get_link = requests.get(url)
    get_link_text = get_link.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(get_link_text,'html.parser')
    for row in soup.findAll('h2', {'class': 'balancedHeadline'}):
        tlist.append(row)

    print(tlist)

get_titles()
```

Comment: There are no `h2` elements with this class on the nytimes homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage is rendered dynamically by js. So you have to use `selenium` to **scrape** it.

Then, the `h2` titles have no class named `balancedHeadline`, so you have to select the `span` inside the `h2`

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

def get_titles():

    tlist = []
    url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
    for row in soup.find_all('h2', {'class': 'esl82me0'}):
        spantext = row.find('span', {'class': 'balancedHeadline'})
        if spantext:
            tlist.append(spantext.text)

    print(tlist)

get_titles()
```

**RESULT:**

```
[
'U.S. Delays Some China Tariffs Until Stores Stock Up for Holidays',
'After a Chaotic Night of Protests, Calm at Hong Kong Airport, for Now',
'Guards at Jail Where Epstein Died Were Sleeping, Officials Say',
'How a Trump Ally Tested the Boundaries of Washington’s Influence Game',
'‘Juul-alikes’ Are Filling Shelves With Sweet, Teen-Friendly Nicotine Flavors',
'A Boom Time for the Bunker Business and Doomsday Capitalists',
'Introducing The 1619 Project'
]
```

**EDIT:**

I didn't see there are some title with no `span`, so I had a test and you'll find all the titles:

**CODE:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

def get_titles():

    tlist = []
    url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
    for row in soup.find_all('h2', {'class': 'esl82me0'}):
        span = row.find('span', {'class': 'balancedHeadline'})
        if span:
            tlist.append(span.text)
        else:
            tlist.append(row.text)

    print(tlist)

get_titles()
```

**RESULTS:**

```
['Your Wednesday Briefing',
 'Listen to ‘The Daily’',
 'The Book Review Podcast',
 'U.S. Delays Some China Tariffs Until Stores Stock Up for Holidays',
 'While visiting a chemical plant, Mr. Trump railed against China, former '
 'President Barack Obama and the news media.',
 'Two counties in California filed a lawsuit to block the administration’s new '
 'green card “wealth” test.',
 'After a Chaotic Night of Protests, Calm at Hong Kong Airport, for Now',
 'Protesters apologized after scenes of violence and disorder at the airport.',
 'Guards at Jail Where Epstein Died Were Sleeping, Officials Say',
 'How a Trump Ally Tested the Boundaries of Washington’s Influence Game',
 'Here are four takeaways from our report on Mr. Broidy.',
 '‘Juul-alikes’ Are Filling Shelves With Sweet, Teen-Friendly Nicotine Flavors',
 'A Boom Time for the Bunker Business and Doomsday Capitalists',
 'The Cold Truth About the Jeffrey Epstein Case',
 '‘My Name Is Darlin. I Just Came Out of Detention.’',
 'Trump and Xi Sittin’ in a Tree',
 'This Drug Will Save Children’s Lives. It Costs $2 Million.',
 'The Battle for Hong Kong Is Being Fought in Sydney and Vancouver',
 'No Need to Deport Me. This Dreamer’s Dream Is Dead.',
 'Threats to Animals: Pesticides. Pollution. President Trump.',
 'Jeffrey Epstein and When to Take Conspiracies Seriously',
 'Why Trump Fears Women of Color',
 'The Religious Hunger of the Radical Right',
 'No, I Won’t Sign Your Petition',
 'Introducing The 1619 Project',
 'A Surfing Adventure in … Ireland?',
 'When the Creepy Carnival Comes to Town']
```

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. Very helpful. Could you tell me how to know if the web page is rendered by js or not?

Comment: You are welcome :-) You can see if you log the page (get_link.text in your case) if there is the same data than your browser display. Or check your developer console and you can see an `event` tag when this is the case.  Please accept the answer if it helps ;-)